# Why are JavaScript runtimes omitted from Rails Gemfiles by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are lots of questions about the dreaded `Could not find a JavaScript runtime` error when running `rails` or `rake`. While the solution is clear, ***why* is it standard to leave the JavaScript framework out of the Gemfile?**

The only reasons I could think of are:

- Fuzzy crowd-sourcing of the testing of the app with different JS frameworks.
- Force newbies to learn about Gemfiles before doing anything useful with Rails.

Both of these seem to do more harm than good to the Rails reputation. Isn't the point of Rails to be up and running as soon as possible? Seems to me that the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) and [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_Configuration) would dictate that developers (and especially newbies)

1. shouldn't have to care about (and much less compare) JS frameworks before starting work any more than they do for SQLite vs. PostgreSQL,
2. shouldn't have to do more configuration before running <strike>an</strike> every app, and in summary
3. should just *download, install and run*, like with pretty much every mainstream app in every other language these days.

Comment: Very good and valid question, but I doubt that anyone will have a definite answer for this one (only speculation, pros/cons). So shouldn't this go into meta?

Comment: I think meta is only for discussions *about SO*. But it might fit better on programmers.SE. I just thought it would fit nicely with all the duplicates related to the core issue :)

Comment: Ah I see - thanks for the hint. Just thought that the question might be a little to broad in nature, but let's see what answers you'll get here.